# Javascript style overriding CSS hover

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, styles, hover

To make this clearer, I'll use my code below:

I have a divider container, "c_container":

```
<div id="c_container">
<div id="c_tab">Menu</div>
<div id="c_main">MenuContent</div>
</div>
```

Then I have CSS that controls it's style:

```
#c_container {
    width: 550px;
    height: 265px;
    position: fixed;
    left: -550px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
#c_container:hover{
    margin-left: 0px;
    left: -40px;
}
```

Then after I update the style using Javascript from an onClick function:

```
function hideForm(){
    var msg = document.getElementById("c_container");
    msg.style.left = "-550px";
}
```

The CSS hover only effects the margin property and doesn't effect the left property as it did before. It's like javascript has locked it.

Comment: Does your actual code also contain improper quoting? You need to use `'` inside the `onclick="..."` string or use `onclick='...'` - basically you cannot use the same quote type inside which was used to quote the the attribute value.

Comment: Sorry, yes it does. I'll edit

Comment: Curious...why are you forcefully hiding `c_container` if it will hide when the user moves the mouse off of it?

Comment: I want the user to be able to click to hide it from within the c_main divider. It makes sense if you saw my web design :)

Comment: Maybe a link to a live server page? Will clear any questions (I think).

Comment: It's only hosted on localhost at the moment.

Comment: Use jQuery if you can (Hidde) provides an example below. Although your CSS is correct, Javascript sets the inline style properties which take precedence, as already mentioned. So you need to control both the *display* and *hiding* of this element with Javascript instead of trying to let CSS pick up the slack. Your CSS will come into play as a fallback for those with Javascript disabled. jQuery is the easiest way to create the exact effect if you don't mind using it.

Answer (score 3):

***jQuery:***

```
//Normal: 
$('elementNameOrID').hover (function () {
    $(this).css('left', 0);
}, function () {
    $(this).animate('left', -500);
}); 

//Nice:
$('elementNameOrID').hover (function () {
    $(this).animate({left: 0});
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({left: -500});
});
```

***JS:***

```
onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("div").style.left = '-550px';
};
```

*Sidenote:* Using `div` as a name for an element is NOT a good idea and very confusing and misleading when reading your code.

Answer (score 2):

Styles added with the JavaScript style are creating an inline style which has higher precedence than your style sheet. To fix this you can add `!important` to your style sheet:

```
#c_container:hover{
    margin-left: 0px;
    left: -40px !important;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the left property gets overridden by javascript not margin-left. If i apply !important to the left property javascript does not effect its position

Comment: Whoops, I added that to the wrong item, meant to add it to `left` not `margin-left`.

Comment: I tried that and then javascript's style.left function doesn't change it's position.

Comment: Yes, I just saw from your other comment that you are clicking from within the div, so I assume you are still 'hovering' when you want to hide it? In that case I don't think there's a lot you can do, either the js style will override the hover or the other way round. I could maybe suggest more if I could see the actual page.

Comment: it was mainly for aesthetic pleasure, but it can be sacrificed. it's ok

Answer (score 1):

Have problem with commas in onclick function ...

```
onclick="document.getElementById('div').style.left='-550px;'"
```

and 'div' is not good name for id.

Your CSS is confusing. For apply DIV tag

```
div {
   position: fixed;
   left: -550px;
}
div:hover{
   left: 0px;
}
```

OR

```
#DIV_ID { ... }
```

OR

```
.CLASSNAME { ...}
```

**EDIT**

I'm recriate your example ... http://jsfiddle.net/PAg9M/1/ and work for me. What you need?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because inline css haves more priority than the one in"style" tag and javascript add inline css.

So should use only javascript to do this-

modify your html-

```
<div id="c_container" onmouseover="style.left='0'" onmouseout="style.left='-550'">
<div id="c_tab">Menu</div>
<div id="c_main">MenuContent</div>
</div>
```

This will sort out your problem.